# Totally Tamely Ramified Field Extension

Tags: field-theory, class-field-theory

I have a question about @nguyen quang do's answer given in following thread:

[correspondence between totally, tamely ramified extension and value groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2651836/correspondence-between-totally-tamely-ramified-extension-and-value-groups)

We consider a totally tamely ramified field extension $L/K$ of degree $e $. Why does it already imply that $L=K({\pi}_L)$.

Here $\pi_L$ is the unique maximal/prime ideal of the ring $\mathcal{O}_L$.

Remark: I'm working with the definitions for totally/ tamely Ramifications from here:
[http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~pete/8410Chapter4.pdf](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/8410Chapter4.pdf)

My considerations:

By definition we have $K = K(\pi_K), L = L(\pi_L)$ and $\pi_K \mathcal{O}_L = \pi_L ^e \mathcal{O}_L$, right?

From here I'm stuck. Does it suffice to show that from $l \in L $ we can conclude that $l^e \in \pi_K  \mathcal{O}_L$. If yes, how could we pull here the root back?